# JavaScript unique identifier for local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, uniqueidentifier

Independent from the HTML id attribute, is there a good way to define a unique element identifier in JavaScript to use with HTML5 local storage?

```
localStorage.setItem('uniqueid', value);
```

Could do this:

```
var uid = ancestor.index(element); // uid = 0

localStorage.setItem(namespace + uid, value);
```

The problem is that if the element order changes, the data is not associated with the right element:

```
var uid = ancestor.index(element); // another element is prepended, so uid = 1

localStorage.getItem(namespace + uid);
```

---

**EDIT**  - real example

HTML code:

```
<ul>
<li aria-hidden="true">foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery code:

```
var ul = $('ul');

ul.find('li').each(function() {

    var element = $(this),
        uid = ul.index(element),
        data = JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem(uid));

    // load
    console.log(data.hidden);

    // save
    this.$window.bind('unload', function() {

        localStorage.setItem(uid, JSON.stringify({
            hidden: typeof element.attr('aria-hidden') === 'string',
        }));
    });
});
```

Now I am using the index of each list item to create a unique identifier. I could set a data-uid with HTML like so:

```
<li data-uid="foo">foo</li>
```

Is there a way to set the unique identifier dynamically?

Comment: Can you use a simple counter? Assign the value to a *data-* property of the element and to a key to the associated data. Increment it each time you add another element and data chunk.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand your suggestion. Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: Create a unique id, use `node.setAttribute('data-myId',id)` to add it the element, then add it to the local storage. You can also store it in an object as `{...,id:node,...}` so access is fast too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data being stored depends on the specific order of elements, that seems to suggest it will not be helpful to persist this data beyond the current page. You may wish to look at `data-*` attributes such as jQuery implements in [`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).

This will allow you to store arbitrary data associated with any element.

Comment: "jQuery ensures that the data is removed when DOM elements are removed via jQuery methods, and when the user leaves the page." The point of using local storage is to remember the data when the user leaves the page.

Comment: I don't want it to depend on the specific order of elements but that's the only way I know of currently. That's why I am asking for an alternative.

Comment: Yes, I understand the point of localStorage. But I'm curious how you can expect to know what data you have in localStorage is associated with elements once they are in a different order. You really need some application-specific identifier to make the association, but it seems like you don't have one.

Comment: @ Michael Mior application-specific identifier? Something like the id attribute then, but that's element-specific.

Comment: Yes, you need something which is element-specific. Your element doesn't necessarily need to have an ID attribute, but you do need some way to associate the element with it's data. It's really hard to give more advice without an example.

Comment: @ Michael Mior added an example. Seems there's no way to give an element a persistent unique id dynamically then?

Comment: Can you not simply use the value of `data-uid` as a key for localStorage? (i.e. foo or bar)?

Comment: Yes but I mean, there's no way to set such a unique id dynamically, with JavaScript.

Comment: Can you provide an example showing where you're at now and explain what you want to do instead of using made-up data?

Comment: I'll see if I can catch you on chat later this evening. I think this requires further discussion.

Comment: Ok, I'm in the JavaScript room. Thanks!

Comment: @DADU let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1151/discussion-between-michael-mior-and-dadu)

Answer (score -4):

```
localStorage.setItem(localStorage.length, value);
```

same as creating a counter and incrementing it each time

note: if you ever delete an entry then the next "new" id will be the same as the last one.

- 0 items in local storage next id created is 0
- 1 items in local storage next id created is 1
- 2 items in local storage next id created is 2
- delete item id 1
- 2 items in local storage next id created is 2 (which over writes the
  previous id 2 record.

One possible workaround is to mark items as "deleted" but not delete them. Obviously that will not work in all cases.

Thanks to @Mike-robinson for pointing this out.